# How does a switch's MAC layer behave when both nodes are at different speed and duplex

Tags: networking, ethernet, switch

I have a network which is connected like this :

```
PC1
|
| (auto neg)
|
Switch1
|
| (10 Mbps Half)
|
Switch2
|
| (auto neg)
|
PC2
```

then everything works fine. Now I just want to know how does switches pass on the traffic when 2 nodes are at different speed (like here, PC node at 1Gbps, another switch's node at 10 Mbps Half). There must be two MACs involved in the switch both running at different speeds. So how does it work ?

Comment: You appear to have created 2 accounts. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

It just receives the packet on one segment, figures out which segment (or segments) to send it on, and sends it exactly as it received it but at a different speed. So the outbound packet has the same source MAC address and destination MAC address as the inbound packet.

The switch has to receive the entire packet before it can begin sending it on the other segment, of course. Cut-through switching is only possible when the two segments run at the same speed.

Answer (score 0):

A fundamental concept is that digital data is easy to store compared to an analog signal.  For instance the old analog telephone network requires a fully connected, active electrical path between two phones for the call to proceed.  But digital data is typically grouped into frames or packets, and the data transfer can buffer (store) the data before forwarding it.

Check the technical specifications for your switches, and you'll probably find out that they are of the store-and-forward variety, rather than a cut-through switch.  Each switch will receive the Ethernet frame in its entirety before the switch tries to forward it on to its next destination.  So each link can operate at its own speed, and there is essentially no interdependence between links regarding speed or full versus half duplexing.

See [Cut-Through and Store-and-Forward Ethernet Switching](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/support/faq/switches/layer-3-gigabit/dgs-series/what-is-the-difference-between-store-and-forward-switching-and-cut-through-switching)

> There must be two MACs involved in the switch both running at different speeds.

Actually it's the PHY, not the MAC (which only handles digital data), that is actually involved in the link speed.  A switch might have just one MAC, and a PHY per port.